# SQL-Server to MySQL equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql-server

What is the equivalent of this SQL-Server code in MySQL?

```
SELECT Property_ID, Property_Type, [URL]
FROM dbo.Properties p OUTER APPLY
 (SELECT TOP 1 i.[URL]
  FROM dbo.Images_Table i
  WHERE i.Property_ID = p.Property_ID
  ORDER BY i.Image_ID
 ) i 
WHERE p.Area LIKE '%po%'
ORDER BY p.Property_ID OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list.  The restriction is that the subquery must return exactly one expression (one column) and at most one row.

```
 SELECT p.property_id
      , p.property_type
      , ( SELECT i.url 
            FROM dbo.images_table i
           WHERE i.property_id = p.property_id
           ORDER BY i.image_id
           LIMIT 1
        ) AS url
   FROM dbo.properties p
  WHERE p.area LIKE '%po%'
  ORDER BY p.property_id
  LIMIT 0,5
```